# Approximating an integral in the from $e^{1/(a+bx/c)}$

Tags: integration, approximate-integration

I want to integrate the equation $e^{1/(a+bx/c)}$ with respect to x, where a, b, c are all constants, but I can't seem to find an approximation for it. Is there a way to approximate this integral or the equation itself?

Comment: Try Taylor series.

Comment: @Saturday I was thinking Taylor series then substitute to integrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

Let $k=\frac b c$
$$I=\int e^{\frac{1}{a+k x}}\,dx$$ Now
$$\frac{1}{a+k x}=t \implies x=\frac{1-a t}{k t}\implies dx=-\frac{dt}{k t^2}\implies I=-\frac 1 k\int \frac{e^t}{t^2}\,dt$$ Use one integration by parts and think about the exponential integral function.

Comment: That seems easier than Taylor expansion+substitution! Thank you!

Comment: @Limona2000. For sure ! This is exact and if you do not access the exponential integral function, now we can build nice approximations. Cheers :-)